# Property 'featured' does not exist on type 'string[]'

Tags: html, angular6

I am building an Angular project with CLI command :`$ ng build --prod` and getting an error of:

```
ERROR in src/app/fetch-api/fetch-api.component.html(5,7): : Property 'featured' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
```

My html code is:

```
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let fetch of fetchApi.data.featured">
            <ul>
                <li><b> {{fetch.description.split('|')[0]}}</b></li>
                <li><youtube-player
                        content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;"
                        [videoId]="fetch.video_id_" (ready)="savePlayer($event)"
                        (change)="onStateChange($event)"></youtube-player> <!-- <iframe width="560" height="315" [src]="myFunction(fetch.video_location)" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
             --></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have problems with `Angular` not `AngularJS`.

The problem with your code is exactly what the error message says. `fetchApi.data` is an array of strings which does not have property `featured`.

You have badly defined types for `fetchApi.data.featured`. Check type declarations in your component.ts file for that object.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, My component code is: `ngOnInit() {
    const scope = this;
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.fetchApi = data;
        console.log(this.fetchApi);
      });
  };` I don't think that there is any issue. I am getting a JSON array from one of my API.

Comment: Did you declared type for `this.fetchApi` ? If so, what is it?